# Bundle is invalid while submitting app to AppStore

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I am unable to submit App on App Store below are the screen shot of AppStore connect version.Following error occurs during AppStore submission

> This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString
>   [3.3.6] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that
>   of the previously approved version [3.5.0].

[image]

Comment: you must update the value for `CFBundleVersion` as well in your `Info.plist` file – check the latest bundle version and choose a bigger number.

Comment: Your previous version was 3.5.0 and now you are submitting it as 3.3.6. use 3.5.1 or higher than 3.5.0

Comment: @MahakMittal you are correct I submitted the build before reading your comment it worked fine.But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The version and build number presented on `info.plist` should be higher. Try using **3.6.0**

**infor.plist**

[image]

**Configuration**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By increasing version and build number to 3.5.1 I was able to submit the App to AppStore.AppStore Connect App version and CFBundleShortVersionString can be differ according to your version control.